# SSIS Excel Source importing individual date columns in different formats

Tags: excel, ssis

I've looked at a number of similar questions but can't find anything relating to the specific issue of different date columns being read in different formats.

My source file (xlsx) has columns Date1 and Date2 - both of which are stored within Excel in Date format.

Using the Excel source (Locale = English (UK)) - the preview shows the data in the way I would expect to see it within my Locale (DD/MM/YYYY) for both columns.

For 'reasons' I want all my columns to be processed as text, so within the Excel source advanced editor I've made all the output columns Unicode String. When I place a data viewer straight after the Excel Source control, Date1 is in DD/MM/YYYY format, but Date2 is in MM/DD/YYYY format! (this continues down the flow to my destination, I'm just using the viewer to prove the issue occurs from the initial source loading)

How is this happening? I've tried IMEX=1 in the connection manager connectionstring but that had no effect.

**EDIT** - more details
The first few rows of source data for Date1 are blank, whereas Date2 has values of 12/10/2015.

By about row 40 of the source, Date1 is populated with 03/05/2011 and Date2 17/02/2016 - here in the data viewer Date1 displays as 03/05/2011 but Date2 displays as 2/17/2016 - note the leading 0 is truncated in this case but not Date1?

Comment: What happens if, instead of the advanced editor, you use a Data Conversion transformation to change the dates to strings?   Does it still handle the two columns differently?

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I've made so many changes I'm now lost so bear with me :) Now Date2 definitely converts differently based on whether I simply change the output column in the advanced editor or use a data conversion transformation (ie it's correct when using the data conversion transformation). However Date1 is now coming through as a Unicode string from source, so I really don't know what I've done there. In any case, can I achieve the same functionality of the data transform at the Excel Source level? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an excel expert unfortunately, so I don't know what you can do in that part of it.   If I were the one having this problem, I would fix it in the dataflow with Data Conversion and/or Derived Column.